Cookie Authorization ASP.NET
I'm having trouble understanding why my user never gets authenticated on frontend.
I make a "Login" API call where I get a jwt token generated in the backend. I manually store the token in cookies.
The problem appears when I need to access an action of a controller in the frontend (from a Razor page) with the [Authorize] attribute and I'm never able to do so because the user is not authenticated.
Is it mandatory to run httpContext.SigInAsyn()? I have seen some apps that don't run this an still the user gets authenticated somehow.
What am I missing?
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
               {
                   options.LoginPath = "/auth";
                   options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/accessdenied";
                   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                   options.SlidingExpiration = true; 
                   double expiresIn = 3600;
                   options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);
                   options.Cookie.Name = SConstants.JWT_COOKIE_NAME;
                   options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
               });

// middleware

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

What I do with the token from the backend:
HttpContext.Response
           .Cookies
           .Append(SConstants.JWT_COOKIE_NAME, 
                   access_token, 
                   new CookieOptions 
                       {
                           HttpOnly = true, 
                           Secure = true 
                       });


Yes, if you are using the asp.net core cookie authentication, you need call the HttpContext.SignInAsync() to generate the authentication ticket, which ties the user identity to the cookie and informs the ASP.NET Core authentication system that the user is signed in.
In your case, JWT won’t automatically sign the user in with cookie authentication, because ASP.NET Core's authentication system doesn’t recognize the token as an authentication ticket unless you explicitly sign the user in.
So you should generate the cookie's ticket and use this ticket to access the controller.
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
        new Claim("FullName", user.FullName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
    };

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
        claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        //AllowRefresh = <bool>,
        // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

        //ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
        // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
        // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

        //IsPersistent = true,
        // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
        // multiple requests. When used with cookies, controls
        // whether the cookie's lifetime is absolute (matching the
        // lifetime of the authentication ticket) or session-based.

        //IssuedUtc = <DateTimeOffset>,
        // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

        //RedirectUri = <string>
        // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
        // redirect response value.
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
        authProperties);

More details, you could refer to this article.
